# Why is the unique ID field in Distance matrix empty for some inputs?

Tags: qgis

I have some coordinates in a .TSV file I import using the delimited text layer button. I have a different set of coordinates (actually, one point) that I import in the same way.

What I've tried so far is the following:

[image: this photo]

I upload the coordinates (test, in pink) using the delimited text layer button.
I upload the localized coordinate using the same method above (test_Sheet(1)).
I wanted to try to accomplish this by going vector-->Analysis Tools-->Distance Matrix.

However for one of those, the one with multiple coordinates, it's not giving me any scroll box for to input the unique ID field. If I switch things around so it's the localized coordinate, it's totally fine no matter what.

Because of this I can't run analysis.
Can anyone figure out what my issue is?

Comment: Export the points to a shapefile, it's complaining that the features don't have an OID/FID/UniqueID field; shapefiles do (called FID) after that it should run. ArcGis complains about the same thing when using an event layer.